# Combinatorial reasoning for the identity $\left ( \sum_{i=1}^n i \right )^2 = \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 \right ) $

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, intuition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intuitive explanation for the identity $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/intuitive-explanation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-left-sum-l)

There is the interesting identity:

$$\left ( \sum_{i=1}^n i \right )^2 = \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 \right ) $$ 
which holds for any positive integer $n$.

I know several was of proving this (finite differences, induction, algebraic tricks etc..), but even so I still find it "weird" that it is even true.

Is there a very nice intuitive way to prove this using some kind of combinatorial argument?  (Like the why the sum of the volume of the first $n$ cubes should be the area of ... not sure here?)

If you have any pretty different proof that could be enlightening I would love to see it.

Thanks a lot!