# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^ni^3=\left(\sum_{i=1}^ni\right)^2$ without evaluating them.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

> Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^ni^3=\left(\sum_{i=1}^ni\right)^2$ without evaluating them.

Of course, they are $\displaystyle n^2(n+1)^2/4$ and $n(n+1)/2$, but is there anymore direct way to show that $\sum i^3=(\sum i)^2$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: [Plenty of brilliant ways...](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61482/49437)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61798/generalisation-of-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-bigg-sum-limits-k