# Proof that $ 1^3+2^3+\cdots +n^3 = (1+2+\cdots+n)^2$ without using induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intuitive explanation for the identity $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/intuitive-explanation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-left-sum-l)

How to prove this without using mathematical induction?

$$1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3 = (1+2+\cdots+n)^2$$

I know how to prove it by induction, is there a different way?

Comment: This question is **not** a duplicate of the question Arjang linked to - generalizations of an identity and alternative proofs of it are different things.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: But it _is_ a duplicate of both http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/intuitive-explanation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-left-sum-l and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18548/combinatorial-reasoning-for-the-identity-left-sum-i-1n-i-right-2-l I merged those two together , and perhaps will merge this one since there are useful answers here not yet brought up over there.